# Getting a URL with Python

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to do something similar to placekitten.com, wherein a user can input two strings after the base URL and have those strings alter the output. I'm doing this in Python, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the URL. In PHP I can do it with query string and $_REQUEST. I can't find a similar method in Python that doesn't rely on CGI.

(I know I could do this with Django, but that's serious overkill for this project.)

Comment: You said you aren't using CGI, and you aren't using Django. What web framework are you using? You have to choose something.  PHP is inherently integrated with a web server, but Python is not.  A web framework provides that bridge.

Comment: Yeah, what are you using? `SimpleHTTPServer`? It completely depends on this.

Comment: Sorry, that would indeed be helpful info! I'm using CherryPy, but since it doesn't really do templating, I'm not sure if I can actually use it for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just by looking at the docs but have you tried it?

```
cherrypy.request.path_info
```

The docs say:

> The ‘relative path’ portion of the Request-URI. This is relative to the script_name (‘mount point’) of the application which is handling this request.

http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.path_info